# How to write a hash function for a std::vector<std::vector<bool>>

Tags: c++, hash, struct, stl, unordered-set

I have a struct which has one variable, a `std::vector<std::vector<bool>>` that represents a grid. One of these structs is equal to another if the grids are equal, or if any rotation of the grids is equal. I'm trying to use an `unordered_set` to store many of these, however, after some research, I've found that I need to have some sort of a hash function. I have never used a hash function before, and the things I've found in reference to it are confusing to me. So, my question, how do I/what is the best way to write a hash function for such a data type, or is it better to just use an unordered set of grids and test the rotations as I add them in?

Some code:

```
int nx, ny;

typedef std::vector<std::vector<bool>> grid;

struct rotateableGrid {
public:
    grid data;
    rotateableGrid(grid data) : data(data) {}
    rotateableGrid(rotateableGrid &rg) : data(rg.data) {}
    bool operator==(const rotateableGrid & rhs) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            if (rotate(c) == rhs.data) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    grid rotate(int amt) {
        if (amt % 4 == 0) return data;

        grid ret(ny, std::vector<bool>(nx));

        for (int x = 0; x < nx; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < ny; y++) {
                switch (amt % 4) {
                case 1:
                    if (x < ny && nx - 1 - y >= 0) ret[x][nx - 1 - y] = data[y][x];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (nx - 1 - x >= 0 && ny - 1 - y >= 0) ret[ny - 1 - y][nx - 1 - x] = data[y][x];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (ny - 1 - x >= 0 && y < nx) ret[x][nx - 1 - y] = data[y][x];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

**Note:** I am using C++ in VS 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is combine the hashes for all the vectors within the matrix. There is an overload of [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash#Standard_specializations_for_library_types) for `std::vector<bool>`. If you try something like this

```
size_t hash_vector(const std::vector< std::vector<bool> >& in, size_t seed)
{
    size_t size = in.size();
    std::hash< std::vector<bool> > hasher;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //Combine the hash of the current vector with the hashes of the previous ones
        seed ^= hasher(in[i]) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }
    return seed;
}
```

To get rotational invariance you would then combine the hashes of all rotations of the grid. As suggested in the comment by @zch you would do this

```
size_t hash_grid(rotateableGrid& in, size_t seed = 92821)
             //  ^^^^^ Should be const, but rotate isn't marked const
{
    return hash_vector(in.data) ^ hash_vector(in.rotate(1).data) ^ hash_vector(in.rotate(2).data) ^ hash_vector(in.rotate(3).data);
}
```

However, because the rotate member of `rotateableGrid` is marked private you will have to declare `hash_grid` as a friend of `rotateableGrid`. To do that you would have to add this inside the definition of `rotateableGrid`

```
friend size_t hash_grid(rotateableGrid&, size_t);
```

Comment: Except this method is not rotation invariant, as was requested in question. The simplest way to deal with this would be to combine hashes of all four rotations with some commutative operation (addition or xor).